# Stackpanel horizontal orientation gap between items

Tags: wpf

I have a StackPanel inside a Grid:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button>Start</Button>
                <Button>Stop</Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

Why there's a gap between the 2 buttons ?

The margin is set to 0 for both buttons.

[image: Buttons]

[image]

Comment: I think the control template of the button is modified. Can you please share the style of the button. There might be some internal elements which has some margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take look if stack panel template is defined and maybe there is defined margin
2. Take look if button template is defined and maybe there is defined margin